# Bit encoding of a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science

**Task:**

Given a set $S$, provide a bit encoding of subsets $S'$ of $S$, i.e. $S' \subseteq S$ with the following two properties:

There is a unique encoding for every subset of $S$.

The endcoding is optimal (i.e. it needs the minimal amount of bits).

**Idea:**

let $X$ be the set $S = \{s_1, \dots, s_n\} $, but ordered in some way (Alphabetically, numeric,...).

We then have the ordered version of $S$, $X = \{x_1, \dots, x_n |\quad x_i \in S, i\in 1,\dots,n\}$.

We now encode every element of $X$, by encoding the index $i$ of each element $x_i \in X$. Each element $x_i$ is encoded using elias gamma encoding, which is defined as follows:

$\lfloor log_2(i)\rfloor$ zeros, then i in binary.

**Example:**

Given $X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\}$

Then we encode each $x_i \in X$ by encoding $i$,
Such that:

```
i=1 -> 1
i=2 -> 0 10
i=3 -> 0 11
i=4 -> 00 100
i=5 -> 00 101
```

And we end up with a set $X' = \{x_1=1, x_2=010, x_3=011, x_4=00100, x_5=00101 \}$

If we then want to encode a subset $S' \subseteq S$, we just have to take the bit encodings from $X'$ and put them into the subset.

Could this idea work or is it the wrong approach?

**EDIT:**

So the solution of the task is the following:

Let $S$ be a set and $|S| = n$.

Let $s_i$ be an element of $S$, i.e. $s_i \in S$, where $i \in [1,n], n \in \mathbb{N}$.

A subset $S' \subseteq S$ has an encoding $enc(S')$.
$enc(S')$ consists of $n$ bits $b_i$, such that:
$$enc(S') = b_1\dots b_n$$
where a bit $b_i$ is set to 1 if $s_i \in S'$, and set to 0 otherwise.

Example:

Let $S = \{A,B,C\}$, then all subsets of $S$ are: $$\{\},\{A\},\{B\},\{C\},\{A,B\},\{A,C\},\{B,C\},\{A,B,C\}.$$
It follows that $S$ and all subsets are encoded as follows:

$$enc(\{A,B,C\}) = 111$$
$$enc(\{A,B\}) = 110$$
$$enc(\{A,C\}) = 101$$
$$enc(\{B,C\}) = 011$$
$$enc(\{A\}) = 100$$
$$enc(\{B\}) =010$$
$$enc(\{C\}) = 001$$
$$enc(\{\emptyset\}) = 000$$

In order to show that the code is optimal, we have to show that the number of subsets of $S$ is $2^n$, if so it can not be encoded with anything less than n bits.

Prove:

Let $S$ be a set and $|S| = n$.

Let $\mathcal{P}(S)$ be the powerset of $S$.

We show that $|\mathcal{P}(S)| = 2^n$.

1. $|\mathcal{P}(S)| = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}$.
       Where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient, which denotes the amount of possibilities to draw $k$ elements from $n$ elements,
       where the order is ignored and every element can only be drawn once.

   The binomial theorem says: $$(x + y)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \cdot x^{n-k} \cdot y^{k}$$

   Using 2. we come to the conclusion that: $$2^n = (1+1)^n \overset{2.}{=} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \cdot 1^{n-k} \cdot 1^{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \overset{1.}{=} |\mathcal{P}(S)| $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for each element $x \in S$ it's either included in a subset or it's not. How can you encode such a *binary* decision between two options?

Alternative hint: how many subsets are there of a set with $n$ elements?

Comment: Hm, for hint 1, i would expect: If i have a set of length $n$, then I use $n$ bits, and set those to 1 which are part of the subset ?

For hint 2:  there are $2^n$ subsets, but how does that help me?

Comment: @Derping Right, and can you cross check that guess with hint number 2?

Comment: Well, I get $2^n$ different encodings.  The encoding are unique (but are they prefix free?), and the minimum/maximum amount of bits is n ?

Comment: @Derping Prefix-free encoding was not part of the requirements, unless you omitted it.

Comment: Hm, well well, I see. Then I have misunderstood the question. I somehow thought of the case, that if you would write all bits in a row, one could not decide anymore what kind of subset is given, and so the code has to be prefix free, in order to ensure a correct decoding.

Comment: @Derping If you write all the bits in a row you still have a first, second, third, etc bit. Each can correspond to one element in $S$.

Comment: added my solution to the post, can you verify whether this is correct?

Comment: @Derping That would work, yes.

Comment: Okay. But how can I prove that this code is optimal? Does it really need the minimum amount of bits?

Comment: @Derping That's where the second hint comes in. Prove that the number of subsets of a set with $n$ elements is $2^n$. That means you can't encode it with anything less than $n$ bits.

Comment: I see, added a prove that the cardinality of the powerset of $S$ is $2^n$.
So from this it follows that you can not encode the subsets of $S$ with less than n bits?

Comment: @Derping I'm sorry, but with all due respect I'm not your personal teacher. A couple questions are okay, but I'm not here to hold your hand all the way.